# Images not being showed in IE , firefox/chrome/others are good !

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I am in need to use [This Class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3220-PHP-Serve-files-for-download-with-resume-support.html) to server multiple files (img/video/mp3) from an article writing site i use , the only and main problem is that :
  All images in the articles should be displayed by that class , and that this class doesn't show images (initiates a download when called by URL) .
I managed to fix that by deleting this line (maybe line 107)

```
header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="'.$this->properties["name"].'";');
```

which served me well in displaying images from chrome and firefox , but IE still initiate a download :( .

is there any way / headers to fix that ?

**Edit :**

I added the following to the meta type :

```
case "jpg": $content_type="image/".$file_extension; break; 
case "gif": $content_type="image/".$file_extension; break; 
case "png": $content_type="image/".$file_extension; break;
```

Comment: What value has `$this->properties["name"]`?

Comment: {anything}.jpg where anything is a-zA-Z0-9_

Comment: @Ronan Dejhero: Well, *attachment* means to download the file instead of displaying it directly; try *inline* instead.

Comment: @Ronan Dejhero: What is the actual header that is being returned?

Comment: Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: public
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Type: image/jpg
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="image_1.jpg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary 
Content-Range: 0-254645");
Content-Length: 254645

Comment: Get rid of the caching headers, Content-Disposition (it's not needed here), and the garbage that isn't even defined: Content-Transfer-Encoding, Content-Description.

Comment: @Julian Reschke : Did that , not working

Comment: Please show the actual contents that  are output

Comment: Also, does it happen for all images or just specific ones? Are GIF files affected too?

Comment: @Pekka : you gotta be kidding , the output is a binary JPG file , that opens with mspaint and any other softwares . plus the link of the downloaded image works fine with firefox/chrome , nothing wrong with the content output am sure of that , did a bit-by-bit file comparison from the source JPG file and they matched !

Comment: @Ronan if the content is 100% identical, then fine. Have you tried it with a GIF image?

Comment: @Pekka : yes , PNG , GIF , JPG not talking about MP3s MP4s and FLVs that worked alright , the problem is in the headers or IE hates me as much as i hate it !

Comment: @Ronan strange. So if you link to the original static resource, it works in IE?

Comment: @Gumbo : The inline worked now , forgot to clear the cache !

Comment: @Pekka : Yes the original static resource works .

Comment: Okay, then my answer is not it - deleting

Comment: Ok , Now how can i accept an answer :p @Gumbo could you post ur answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With setting *Content-Disposition* to *attachment* is actually intended to be used not to display the resource directly:

> Bodyparts can be designated `attachment' to indicate that they are separate from the main body of the mail message, and that their display should not be automatic, but contingent upon some further action of the user.

But although the [*Content-Disposition* header field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1806) is rather part of MIME and not part of HTTP, it “has been proposed as a means for the origin server to suggest a default filename if the user requests that the content is saved to a file.” (See [HTTP/1.1 – 19.5 Additional Features](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1))

Additionally to that, the use of the special media type *application/octet-stream* is recommended to imply a download:

> If this header is used in a response with the application/octet-stream content-type, the implied suggestion is that the user agent should not display the response, but directly enter a `save response as...' dialog.

But since you want to resource to be displayed directly, use the *Content-Disposition* value *inline* instead. With this you can use the *filename* parameter as well to specify a file name different from the URL’s.

See also [Julian Reschke’s *Test Cases for HTTP Content-Disposition header field and the Encodings defined in RFC 2047 and RFC 2231/5987*](http://greenbytes.de/tech/tc2231/) for some further information on the encodings used to encode the *filename* parameter.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that IE still required a valid Content-Type header (Assuming the class doesn't supply one for images since it was just forcing a download). Probably need to change this piece of code:

```
switch( $file_extension ) { // the file type
  case "mp3": $content_type="audio/mpeg"; break;
  case "mpg": $content_type="video/mpeg"; break;
  case "avi": $content_type="video/x-msvideo"; break;
  case "wmv": $content_type="video/x-ms-wmv";break;
  case "wma": $content_type="audio/x-ms-wma";break; 
  default: $content_type="application/force-download";
}
```

and add the image extensions and their associated MIME type.